# EGit zip archive for offline install

Tags: eclipse, egit

I wanted to get EGit plug-ins for Eclipse installed on a machine that is not connected to the internet. However the official repository presently seems to be only allowing it to be installed online from within Eclipse and not as zip archive, as used to be possible earlier, AFAIK.

Moreover I wanted EGit for Eclipse 3.4, which is an older version. Is there some way to install the desired EGit version I want, as a downloadable archive suitable for offline installation.

Answer (score 1):

The [EGit download page](https://eclipse.org/egit/download/) offers a zip archive of the p2 repository.

After downloading this archive, you can install it though *Help > Install New Software > Add > Archive*

However, according to [this FAQ](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/FAQ#What_versions_of_Eclipse_does_EGit_target.3F), recent EGit versions require at least Eclipse 3.8.